# Angular 14 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')

Tags: angular

I have a `header` component. In header component I want to create `header-user-menu`  component dynamically when user logged in. But I get error. In header template, I have added both dynamic and static components in order to check if there is a problem with the template but static component works on the other hand dynamic component does not work

header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  private dynamicHeaderUserMenu: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('appHeaderUserMenu', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) set appHeaderUserMenu(
    vcRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) {
    if (vcRef) {
      this.dynamicHeaderUserMenu = vcRef;
    }
  }

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //initialize dynamic components
    this.subs.push(
      this.isLoggedIn$.subscribe((loggedIn) => {
        if (loggedIn) {
          const createRef = this.dynamicHeaderUserMenu.createComponent(HeaderUserMenuComponent);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

header.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="showUMenu" f>
    <app-header-user-menu></app-header-user-menu>
    <ng-template #appHeaderUserMenu></ng-template>
</div>
```

The error is as below
`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createComponent')`

Comment: Did you make sure that `HeaderUserMenuComponent` was inside your module?

Comment: Yes it is in the module. I have tried it in footer component and did work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vcRef` is not defined in the constructor. Since you declared as static, it will get instanciated at `ngOnInit` at best.

So try moving the code of your constructor into your `ngAfterViewInit` function, or in a new `ngOnInit` function.

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('appHeaderUserMenu', { read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) 
  vcRef!: ViewContainerRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    //initialize dynamic components
    this.subs.push(
      this.isLoggedIn$
        .pipe(filter(v => !!v), first())
        .subscribe((loggedIn) => {
          if (loggedIn) {
            const createRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(HeaderUserMenuComponent);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Would you add your code here so that i get it better? @

Comment: @CelalettinTurgut did it, please have a look

Comment: unfortunately did not work. I get the same error

Comment: @Celalettin is your ng template in a ngif statement? Please poste your full html code

Comment: Yes there is an if statement but static `<app-header-user-menu></app-header-user-menu>` works, dynamic template does not work. I have updated the post

Comment: Then your view ref is not static. Try removing the ngif, it will work. Now you only have to find when to call the logic, at the right time.